# Why can't this button have border-radius?

Tags: html, css

The red border is only for reference. I have tried `overflow: hidden` but it didn't work. I am trying to have the same border radius as the red border. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```css
*,*::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --violet: #8F00FF;
}

.rating {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 8px rgba(172, 169, 169, 0.1);
}

button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rating span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interface</title>

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS Link -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
        
        <!-- <div class="single-card">
           

            
        </div> -->
    
        <div class="rating">
            <button>+</button>
            <span>12</span>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add ``border-radius`` on button

Comment: The border-radius on button is reset to 0 through bootstraps reboot.scss. But setting overflow for the div, should work.

Comment: Why not use input="number"? If you don't, you then need to make your control accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` for `.rating` class.

```
.rating {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

OR you just need to add `!important` rule for `border-radius` of `button`. With this way, you don't have to add `overflow` for `.rating`.

```
button {
 ...
 border-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

---

```css
*,*::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --violet: #8F00FF;
}

.rating {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 8px rgba(172, 169, 169, 0.1);
    overflow: hidden;
}

button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.rating span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interface</title>

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS Link -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
        
        <!-- <div class="single-card">
           

            
        </div> -->
    
        <div class="rating">
            <button>+</button>
            <span>12</span>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `overflow: hidden` to `.rating` which would help to fully cover the inner element with the border radius

```css
*,*::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --violet: #8F00FF;
}

.rating {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 8px rgba(172, 169, 169, 0.1);
    overflow: hidden; /*The change is here*/
}

button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rating span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interface</title>

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS Link -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
        
        <!-- <div class="single-card">
           

            
        </div> -->
    
        <div class="rating">
            <button>+</button>
            <span>12</span>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to bootstrap because in bootstrap `<button>` tag is already given `border-radius:0` so you can't change it on direct tags instead you can make your `button` a class and give it to `<button>` tag.

```css
*,*::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --violet: #8F00FF;
}

.rating {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 8px rgba(172, 169, 169, 0.1);
}

.button {
border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
align-items: center;
color: var(--violet);
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden;    
  }

.rating span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--violet);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interface</title>

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS Link -->
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
        
        <!-- <div class="single-card">
           

            
        </div> -->
    
        <div class="rating">
            <button class="button">+</button>
            <span>12</span>
            <button class="button">-</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```